# Unwanted padding in CATextLayer

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, core-text

I am having a problem of drawing a character in a CATextLayer such that the layer is exactly the size of the character.

I use the code below to get the size of the glyph corresponding to the character in the string. At the moment I am neglecting diacretics, so that I am assuming that there is a one to one correlation between glyphs and characters.

I also get nice bounding box values for several characters for the Helvetica font at size 128pt:

```
Character | x   | y     | width | height |
B         | 9.4 |   0.0 | 70.8  | 91.8   |
y         | 1.3 | -27.4 | 61.2  | 96.0   |
```

I am not sure where the origin of the coordinate system is located in which the coordinates are expressed. I am assuming that (0,0) is at the very left and vertically located on the baseline of the font. That is why 'y' has a negative y value.

I am using this code to calculate the size of a capital B and resize its CATextLayer accordingly.

```
- (CATextLayer *) testTextLayer
{
    CATextLayer *l = [CATextLayer layer];
    l.string = @"B";
    NSUInteger len = [l.string length];
    l.fontSize =128.f;
    CGColorRef blackColor = CGColorCreateGenericGray(0.f, 1.f);
    l.foregroundColor = blackColor;
    CGColorRelease(blackColor);

    // need to set CGFont explicitly to convert font property to a CGFontRef
    CGFontRef layerFont = CGFontCreateWithFontName((CFStringRef)@"Helvetica");
    l.font = layerFont;

    // get characters from NSString
    UniChar *characters = (UniChar *)malloc(sizeof(UniChar)*len);
    CFStringGetCharacters((__bridge CFStringRef)l.string, CFRangeMake(0, [l.string length]), characters);

    // Get CTFontRef from CGFontRef
    CTFontRef coreTextFont = CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont(layerFont, l.fontSize, NULL, NULL);

    // allocate glyphs and bounding box arrays for holding the result
    // assuming that each character is only one glyph, which is wrong
    CGGlyph *glyphs = (CGGlyph *)malloc(sizeof(CGGlyph)*len);
    CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(coreTextFont, characters, glyphs, len);

    // get bounding boxes for glyphs
    CGRect *bb = (CGRect *)malloc(sizeof(CGRect)*len);
    CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs(coreTextFont, kCTFontDefaultOrientation, glyphs, bb, len);
    CFRelease(coreTextFont);

    l.position = CGPointMake(200.f, 100.f);

    l.bounds = bb[0];

    l.backgroundColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0.f, .5f, .9f, 1.f);

    free(characters);
    free(glyphs);
    free(bb);

    return l;
}
```

This is the result I am getting from the above code. It seems to me that the size is correct, however there is some kind of padding taking place around the character.

[image: Result of the B on a CATextLayer]

Now **my questions**

1. Am I right with the assumption of the origin of the bounding box of the glyph?
2. How can one draw the letter such that it fits neatly into the layer, without this padding? Or alternatively, how can one control this padding?

Maybe I am missing an obvious point here. Is there now way after setting the size and the font of the layer to shrink wrap the layer around the character in a defined way (meaning with optional padding, a bit like in CSS)?

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about creating a `CGPath` from a glyph with `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph` and then getting its bounding box with `CGPathGetBoundingBox`?

An alternative would be to create a `CTRun` somehow and use the `CTRunGetImageBounds` function which also returns a "tight" bounding box, but this probably requires more lines of code than the aforementioned approach and you'd need to have a graphics context.

Comment: That is an interesting approach. This would solve the problem of the bounding box with an origin coordinate smaller than zero. So one just draws the path in the grahics context and bypassing the CATextLayer mechanism of setting the string property?

Comment: I hadn't really thought about the drawing part, but yes, unless you need other features of `CATextLayer`, you could certainly do that.

Comment: there is another problem with that: I would like to align multiple text layers according to their baselines, so with that I would like to get the overall size of the character including the padding.

Comment: Hmm, you might still be better off by drawing the text yourself as it isn't documented anywhere how exactly `CATextLayer` calculates its layout. I wouldn't know how to get the baselines from a `CATextLayer`, but it's easy to do if you draw with Core Text.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this has to do with the built-in space around letters. Their bounding box usually includes some amount of space that serves as a general spacing if you assemble glyphs in a line. These are then optimized with kerning tables.

And yes, extracting the actual bezier path is a very good method of getting a tight bounding box. I have been doing that for years, though I have no experience using CATextLayers.

Comment: OK, so taking the bezier path would give me the size of the glyph without the padding. But for displaying it I would have to use CoreGraphics directly. I will look up the CoreText API to find out if one could include the spaces into the measurement of the Glyph.